# How to listen to scroll event on a Bootstrap modal?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, events, scroll, modal-dialog

I have a really long bootstrap modal like the last example [here](http://jschr.github.io/bootstrap-modal/). I want to detect if user scrolls when the modal is open.

I tried

```
document.addEventListener('scroll', function(event) {
        console.log("Scrolling");
});
```

also tried

```
$(document).on("scroll","#myModalID",function() {
     // I tried targeting .modal-body and .modal-content too
     console.log("Scrolling");
});
```

and

```
$(window).on("scroll",function() {
     console.log("Scrolling");
});
```

All these are working until I open the modal. But when the modal is open none of the above code works. Works again when I close the modal and scroll.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should notice that the `scroll` event is not bubbled, so you cannot attach handler on some parent element (like `document`) or use event delegating with `.on` in jQuery.

Just select the element directly (because you have its id defined), like this:

```
document.getElementById('myModalID')
        .addEventListener('scroll', function(event) {
    console.log("Scrolling");
});
```

Or for jQuery:

```
$('#myModalID').on("scroll", function() {      
  console.log("Scrolling");
});
```

That should work (and I've already tried it).

Comment: Man, you are a life saver :)

Comment: @Hopeless How would you do this in React?

Comment: @claireablani sorry I've just heard about react but never learnt or experienced with it.

Answer (score 0):

**>> BOOTSTRAP 5.x** >> FULL SCREEN MODE

if you are using `.modal-fullscreen` in modal dialog, then scroll Listener for `.getElementById('myModalID')` **will not work!**  because the dialog itself stands still, and the scrolling happens only inside the modal body

everything worked after I added a listener to the modal-body:

```
document.querySelector('#myModalID .modal-body')
        .addEventListener('scroll', function(event) {
            console.log("Scrolling");
        });
```

--

P.S. I spent a lot of time not understanding why `.querySelector('.modal-body')` didn't work until I realized that I have multiple dialogs on the page ‍♂️ and `.querySelector` gets the wrong dialog ‍♂